# Получить дату заданного дня недели, исходя из текущей даты Java

Tags: java, android, дата, calendar

На основании текущей даты, нужно получить дату, выбранного дня недели, следующего по дате после него.
Пример: Сегодня вторник, выбран понедельник, нужно получить дату понедельника следующей недели.

Текущую дату, получаю таким вот образом:

```
Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: В чем конкретно заключается проблема? Непонятно, как посчитать? Непонятно, как перевести дату в день недели? В чем-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант для тех, кто не понимает почему суббота и почему делить по модулю в принятом ответе. :)

```
int dayOfWeek = 2; // Monday
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int weekday = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// calculate how much to add
int days = dayOfWeek - weekday;
if (days < 0) days += 7;
now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);

// now is the date you want
Date date = now.getTime();
String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println("dateStr = " + dateStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    int dayOfWeek = 2; // Monday
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int weekday = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // calculate how much to add
    int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + dayOfWeek) % 7;
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);

    // now is the date you want
    Date date = now.getTime();
    String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);
    System.out.println("dateStr = " + dateStr);
```

Вывод: `dateStr = пн 20.08.2018`

Comment: Неправильный результат для "текущего" дня недели. Сегодня пятница, если искать дату следующей пятницы, то выдаст сегодняшнюю дату, а должна быть дата через неделю.

Comment: @Эникейщик Автор просил оставить как есть, если день тот же (см. комментарии)

Comment: Ок :) (10 символов)

Answer (score 0):

Значения переменных:

- `date` -  выбран понедельник;
- `d` -  дата понедельника следующей недели.

---

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: Думаю, автор хотел чтобы указав словами "Понедельник", мы получили ДАТУ понедельника, следующего за текущей датой. Т.е., надо не 1 прибавить, а рассчитать сколько дней на основе текущей и выбранной даты

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець да, опираясь от текущей даты, необходимо получить дату выбранного дня недели, следующего за ним (или оставить как есть, если день недели тот же)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Вы также можете получить дату понедельника на текущей недели, опираясь от текуущей даты, тогда считать дни вам не нужно.